# Match two regex patterns in one preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Due to limitations in my script, I've come across a problem where I need to make sure a string matches one of two regex patterns while only calling `preg_match()` once.

Here's some of my code:

```
public static function get_file_host_from_link($link)
{
    foreach(Filehosts::$file_hosts as $key => $val)
    {
        if(preg_match("#{$val["regex"]}#", $link))
        {
            // We have a match, return this file host information
            return $key;
        }
    }
    // We've looped through all the file hosts and it hasn't matched,
    // return false
    return false;
}
```

Now, the problem with matching Fileserve.com URL's is that there can be two types of valid URL structures. One of them is:

```
http://www.fileserve.com/file/aHd8AHD
```

and the other:

```
http://www.fileserve.com/file/zR8VJVM/file_name.zip
```

At the moment, I can match the first structure perfectly fine using this regex: `^http://www.fileserve.com/file/[a-zA-Z0-9]+$` but I also need to match the other URL structure using something like this: `http://www.fileserve.com/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/[a-zA-Z0-9_-\.]+$`. How can I do this with my existing code and only calling `preg_match()` once? I thought about something like this:

`(^http://www.fileserve.com/file/[a-zA-Z0-9]+$|http://www.fileserve.com/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/[a-zA-Z0-9_-\.]+$)`

which to my knowledge means "match the first regex pattern OR the second one", but I have no idea if that'd work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following should work:

```
^http://www.fileserve.com/file/[a-zA-Z0-9]+(/[-a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+)?$
```

The `?` after everything in the parentheses makes it optional.

Also, note that the character class `[a-zA-Z0-9_-\.]` is invalid because `-` specifies a range unless it is escaped or at the start.

You either want `[-a-zA-Z0-9_\.]` or `[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]` (I used the first in my answer).

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of using an optional group... thank you!